# admin_enqueue_scripts not rending JS file correctly

Tags: admin, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I'll keep this short and sweet, I want to load a JS file in the admin panel as part of my plugin, and through tons of research I have a few different options that have all ended with the same problem that no one else seems to be experiencing so finally I'm posting for a solution here.

When I use the following code I get an error:

```
function register_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('payee',plugins_url('iBudget/modules/payee/payee.js',__FILE__));
}
function payee_init($hook){
    wp_enqueue_script('payee');
}

add_action ("admin_print_styles-post.php", "payee_init");
add_action ("admin_init", "register_scripts");
```

ERROR: /wp-content/plugins/iBudget/modules/payee/iBudget/modules/payee/payee.js/?ver=3.3.1:1
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

No matter how I attempt to enqueue the scrip I get this error even though the JS file simple says:
    alert("test");

Now the interesting nugget is this, if I include the JS directly in the function everything works fine:

```
function payee_init($hook){
?>
<script>
    alert("test");
</script>
<?
}
add_action ("admin_print_styles-post.php", "payee_init");
```

Basically I need to know why this error is coming up, I believe I'm loading the script correctly for what I need but not sure why this conflict is there and not even sure where else to look for a solution.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

You action filter is wrong.

First change this function name `function register_scripts` , it's a bad name, use something unique.

Second change `add_action ("admin_print_styles-post.php", "payee_init");`

to a proper hook like `add_action ("wp_enqueue_scripts", "payee_init");`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on this. Had to take a quick break from that project so haven't had the chance to try your suggestion but I'll let you know once I do it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: wp_enqueue_scripts is for loading scripts on the front end. You'd want to use admin_enqueue_scripts for the admin side.